# Bundling SCSS and importing from node_modules

Tags: css, webpack, sass, postcss

I'm trying to bundle all my CSS but i'm running into a few issues.

When I do `@import "materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss";` it fails because it can't resolve the `components`

When I try `@import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css";` it bundles but it doesn't namespace

[image]

```
.frb-app {
  @import "materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss";
  @import "frb-dx-overrides.scss";
}
```

postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  syntax: "postcss-scss",
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "postcss-preset-env": {},
    cssnano: {}
  }
};
```

Loader.js

```
// require("select2/dist/select2.min.css");
require("./css/frb-pmo.scss");
```

Webpack:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      query: {
        presets: [
          [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
              useBuiltIns: "entry",
              targets: {
                ie: "9"
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.(s*)css$/,
      use: [
        "style-loader",
        { loader: "css-loader", options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
        "postcss-loader"
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader: "url?limit=10000!img?progressive=true"
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file-loader?name=bundle/font-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]?mimetype=image/svg+xml"
    },
    {
      test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file-loader?name=bundle/font-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]?mimetype=application/font-woff"
    },
    {
      test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file-loader?name=bundle/font-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]?mimetype=application/font-woff"
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file-loader?name=bundle/font-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]?mimetype=application/octet-stream"
    },
    {
      test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: "file-loader?name=bundle/font-[sha512:hash:base64:7].[ext]"
    }
  ]
},
```